# Confirm This Standard Library Bug Relating to Allocators in MSVC 2015 RC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bug-reporting

Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <class T> struct my_allocator : std::allocator<T> {
    //This overriding struct causes the error
    template <class U> struct rebind {
        typedef my_allocator<T> other;
    };

    //Ignore all this.
    typedef std::allocator<T> base;
    typename base::pointer allocate(typename base::size_type n, std::allocator<void>::const_pointer /*hint*/=nullptr) { return (T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*n); }
    void deallocate(typename base::pointer p, typename base::size_type /*n*/) { free(p); }
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) {
    std::vector<int,my_allocator<int>> vec;
    return 0;
}
```

GCC likes it.
ICC likes it.
Clang likes it.
Even MSVC 2013 likes it.
But MSVC 2015 RC spits out:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test Alloc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(579): error C2664: 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<my_allocator<int>>::deallocate(int *,unsigned int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Container_proxy *' to 'int *'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(579): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(574): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>>::_Free_proxy(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Alloc=my_allocator<int>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(541): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>>::_Free_proxy(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Alloc=my_allocator<int>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(668): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Alloc=my_allocator<int>
1>          ]
1>  c:\users\ian mallett\desktop\test-alloc\main.cpp(18): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<int,my_allocator<int>>' being compiled
```

Related program give similarly fishy sounding errors.  Here are two:
**error C2664: 'void std::_Wrap_alloc>::deallocate(int *,unsigned int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Container_proxy *' to 'int *'**
**cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Wrap_alloc>' to 'const aligned_allocator &'**

Boolean question: is this a bug?  Iff it is, I will ([try](https://superuser.com/questions/942441/i-cant-submit-a-bug-report-because-the-bug-reporter-has-a-bug)) to submit it.

[EDIT: as noted in the comments, this *only occurs* in debug mode.  In release mode, it compiles and executes fine.]
[EDIT: much simpler example]

Comment: Might be irrelevant, but adding declarations to namespace `std` is UB.

Comment: @cpplearner That's not true. There are exceptions, see [Extending the namespace `std`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I don't think any of these exceptions apply here.

Comment: What if you turn off the diagnostic mode of the MSVC standard library?

Comment: I have edited the question to not put code in `std::`; the error still occurs. @UlrichEckhardt running in release mode causes it to compile/run successfully.

Comment: It is just buggy code, you don't support rebind.  Many places where you can find out how to create your own allocator type, nothing that should ever be repeated here :)

Comment: My guess is that the diagnostic mode wraps your allocator to trap misuses. Assuming @Hans Passant is right (I have honestly no experience with implementing STL-style allocators), a functioning `rebind()` implementation in your allocator might be necessary for that, which would explain this behaviour and make it a bug in your code indeed. Have you tried diagnostic mode for other standard libraries (`#define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Boolean question: is this a bug?

`false`.

---

Although the template error given by MSVC here is surpassingly unhelpful, the error here is mine (reassuring since this version of the standard library is shipping today).

I created this allocator (and later, the reduced test case) from a variety of sources, which is why I assumed it was correct.  However, as suggested in the comments, I checked again, this time exhaustively against the documentation.

The missing component here is one of the copy constructors (the template one that can't be auto-generated).  This only shows up when the `rebind` struct is defined since the `rebind` struct overrides the same struct in the parent class (which, since it's in the parent class, ultimately causes the *parent's* copy constructor to be called, so there's no problem (except that it's technically wrong)).

---

The interesting thing here is that the error didn't occur until now.  As I said, GCC, Clang, and MSVC 2013 all like it (even with their respective debug modes).  It's just that none of these *happened* to call the template copy constructor.  Nevertheless, it *is* specified by the standard, so again, the error is ultimately mine.

Congratulations to the MSVC compiler team, and sorry for the noise! :D

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, I ran into the exact same problem and you probably saved me some hours!